# How can I solve the import error for the module util while running cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, python-2.7, executable, importerror, cx-freeze

I have Python version 2.7, cx_freeze version 5.0 and Ubuntu 16.04.

On running the command `python2 setup.py build`in the requisite directory, I am getting the following error:

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 39, in <module>
    executables = executables
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 618, in Freeze
    import cx_Freeze.util
ImportError: No module named util
```

cx_freeze has its source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/e1ba6ec6eaad090a76b7095eeb12d15f803a3bde/cx_Freeze/?at=default). I thought of downloading the util file to the cx_freeze folder on my local machine but neither did I get it nor am I sure of the validness of this method.

So, how do I solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried installing cx_freeze via pip?

Comment: Yeah. I have installed cx_freeze, using pip. Installation isn't a problem. But creating an executable file is.